# Many many issues, eclipse, android MediaPlayer, etc

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

I've recently started android programming, and I'm extremely frustrated to say the least with a lot of things that to me seem simple but are totally holding me back from making any progress. The first of which is the "my first app" hello world that I started a tutorial from http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html
This tutorial worked fine when I was originally looking into android a while ago. Then when I came back after learning a bunch of java this program will no longer work unless I change the target-sdk to version 10 (I found that solution after extensive searching on this site).

Then I moved on to starting tutorials by thenewboston

All of these work fine as long as I didn't use any new targetsdkversion, so I'm wondering what happened that everywhere I go looking for tutorials I can't find anything that will actually work on the current ADT(4.4W and L are what my eclipse automatically set up) and eclipse (indigo). I'll also get issues saying lint isn't working, or trouble with android SDK content loader when I'm not even doing anything.

I've also found snippets of code example on the developer website that I linked earlier that don't work when implemented either

So, am I missing something, is that just old documentation, or is something up with eclipse and ADT? I'm just so frustrated that everything wants to bug out on me when I'm just trying to follow simple introductory tutorials and I don't even know where to turn for tutorials that I can trust to work..

edit:removed code because it wasn't needed.

Comment: @Dag81 - This is a question and answer site for specific technical questions. I would suggest you look for an Android forum to post in where those with some would be able to guide you towards the kinds of answers you are looking for. If you want to post here, ask much more specific questions, and you are likely to get more help. Don't make people sift through your mess to find what you did wrong.

Comment: More specifically, I want to know if there are known issues with the current eclipse indigo, android 4.4W, that make it so the very first tutorial from the official site doesn't even work. Because I spent hours finding a solution for that one tiny thing, when you would think that it should work before they put it as a tutorial. So I don't know if my software is just bad or if I'm dealing with old material or what. The code is expand on that fact. If someone knows there's an issue with resources then I know that I don't have to spend 6 hours trying to figure out something that doesn't work ever

Comment: What version of SDK tools and Build Tools do you have installed? There were some issues shortly after the release of L.

Comment: From looking in my SDK manager i have "android SDK tools rev. 23.0.2"
and build tools rev. 20
and I'm using SDK platform android 4.4W(API20)

oh and my eclipse help says it is indigo service release 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To not get blocked What you can do is continue to set "targetVersion as '19'" instead of setting it to 20 or so. Ensure that you've downloaded API19 through SDK Manager and create the AVDs with that targetSDK version for checking you apps.

That way you can proceed ahead with your coding and later when things get resolved by google for API20...you can always comeback to that new version. This way you can follow 'TheNewBoston' and start coding in Android.

I also recommend 'Slidenerd' tutorials over youtube as well for the beginner.

BTW, I've also selected 'Blank Activity / Empty Activity" during the project creation with API19 and been able to move ahead with my coding.

The Google Bug thread about this latest version issue can be tracked here : [The google bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419)

Answer (score 0):

As a beginning developer, I suggest you use API 19. It has been out for a while and is more stable than L or Google Wear.

Comment: I appreciate it. Maybe it is good to go with the old school stuff because most of the resources out there seem to be fairly old, at least that I could find

Comment: @Dag89 L and API 20 are less than a month old, so most tutorials haven't been updated yet to use them.