# Android API 20L preview and API 204.4W

Tags: android, eclipse, api, android-layout, sdk

here I face one problem after updating this both API level 20 (L and W). in my XML Graphical view the layout is not generated instead it is showing me this error:

**Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?**
Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.

and also shows an error in res/values/styles.xml in this line

style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light

I use Eclipse juno.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple, what you can do is `select API 19 in the graphical layout` and `keep targetSdkVersion="19"` and that should solve your problem. Basically the issue is with API20 bundles by google.

More insight about the issues with API 20L or 20W are already highlighted at below SO questions already...I've also responded with the google bug tracking link. Please have a look at those...

[Many many issues, eclipse, android MediaPlayer, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771268/many-many-issues-eclipse-android-mediaplayer-etc/24771746#24771746)

[latest 'ADT BUNDLE' open as JUNO eclipse for windows 7 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473212/latest-adt-bundle-open-as-juno-eclipse-for-windows-7-64-bit/24522992#24522992)

Hope this helps...